# Can I host my React Native app to my website using cpanel?

Tags: react-native, cpanel, web-hosting, react-native-web

I'm currently developing a website using React Native, when I read about React Native I got the info that React Native can be used as both a web application and a mobile application, so I tried it.

Currently, my website is finished and can be run on localhost

but right now I have a problem when I want to host the website using Cpanel.

Previously I wanted to ask, can React Native be hosted as a website?

Comment: make build of your react native web. It will generate static website. which you can host on cpanel as normal web

Comment: Can you show me how to build this? Because in mine it just shows the code in index.js instead of my app. I have tried to follow this tutorial https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6 but still, it just shows index.js

Comment: can you share your project with sandbox or snack ?

Comment: do you mean this? https://codesandbox.io/s/github/devincalmt/contoh_project

Comment: That is part of my project. Should I add node_modules? I never used sandbox before

Answer (score 3):

Run Following command in your project

```
 expo build:web
```

it will generate web-build folder. inside build folder all your static, assets, js and html files are located.

- now its time to upload you static file to c-panel

open your c-panel account and go file manager and select your domain where you want to go live with web-build (react-native-web).

Upload web-build's folder content to your it will take few minuts and you can visit your domain your site will be live on specific domain